# Codeigniter : database configuration

Tags: codeigniter

I am beginner for CI so don’t have good knowledge.

My problem is:

I am not using any database. All the records are fetched from JSON.
Therefore I don’t think I need to configure database…

As said by CI, it doesn’t necessarily ask for database.

So my database.php configuration is :

```
$active_group = ‘default’;
$active_record = FALSE;

$db[‘default’][‘hostname’] = ‘’;
$db[‘default’][‘username’] = ‘’;
$db[‘default’][‘password’] = ‘’;
$db[‘default’][‘database’] = ‘’;
$db[‘default’][‘dbdriver’] = ‘mysql’;
$db[‘default’][‘dbprefix’] = ‘’;
$db[‘default’][‘pconnect’] = TRUE;
$db[‘default’][‘db_debug’] = TRUE;
$db[‘default’][‘cache_on’] = FALSE;
$db[‘default’][‘cachedir’] = ‘’;
$db[‘default’][‘char_set’] = ‘utf8’;
$db[‘default’][‘dbcollat’] = ‘utf8_general_ci’;
$db[‘default’][‘swap_pre’] = ‘’;
$db[‘default’][‘autoinit’] = TRUE;
$db[‘default’][‘stricton’] = FALSE;
```

It works in my local system but doesn’t work in live server. I am so surprised.

Then I provided hostname, username, password and dbdriver, it works.

My question is that, is that necessary to provide all the details if I am not using database?

Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: make sure you are not auto loading database library in autoload.php

Answer (score 0):

just dont call the Database class dont put it in the autoload.php 
CI dont force you to use database

Comment: I did but it shows error "Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in E:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\system\core\Loader.php on line 884"

Comment: I got the error. Now it works.
Thanks Raheel and Touti for the nice suggestion. :)